# Cast error between Location and SelectedCustomerLocation

Tags: c#, acumatica

We have a customization where we are running a processing screen against customer locations.  When we try to update the location in the Location cache, we are getting the following error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 
'PX.Data.PXCache`1[PX.Objects.AR.SelectedCustomerLocation]' to type 
'PX.Data.PXCache`1[PX.Objects.CR.Location]'.
```

Here is a simplified version of the code we are using.  The `ProcessLocation` method is the PXProcessing delegate:

```
public class LocationMaint_Extension : PXGraphExtension<LocationMaint>
{
    public virtual void ProcessLocation(Location loc)
    {
        LocationExt locExt = loc.GetExtension<LocationExt>();

        locExt.UsrCustomField = "New Value";
        Base.Caches<Location>().Update(loc);
    }
}
```

We are aware that SelectedCustomerLocation derives from SelectedLocation, which derives from Location.  Because of that, we would expect the above code to run successfully, since there is an inheritance present.

If we write the following code, the method succeeds, and the screen is updated successfully.  However, the change we made to the custom field is not persisted to the database:

```
public class LocationMaint_Extension : PXGraphExtension<LocationMaint>
{
    public virtual void ProcessLocation(Location loc)
    {
        LocationExt locExt = loc.GetExtension<LocationExt>();

        locExt.UsrCustomField = "New Value";
        Base.Caches<SelectedCustomerLocation>().Update(loc as SelectedCustomerLocation);
        // We had this code in as well, which did not seem to help
        Base.Caches<SelectedCustomerLocation>().Persist(PXDBOperation.Insert);
        Base.Caches<SelectedCustomerLocation>().Persist(PXDBOperation.Update);
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In C# (and .NET generally), you cannot cast an object of type `G<Derived>` to `G<Base>` where `G` is a generic type.  This is kind of a pain sometimes.  In the past I have made custom methods to do this, like for a `List<T>` you might use something like this:

```
static List<TBase> Upcast<TBase, TDerived>(this List<TDerived> list) 
    where TDerived : TBase 
{
    var result = new List<TBase>();
    foreach (var d in list)
    {
        result.Add(d);
    }
    return result;

}
```

Comment: Hi JamesFaix, thanks for posting an answer.  The types in question are not actually generic types, they are `Location` and `SelectedCustomerLocation`.  We did already try creating a new `Location` object for the `Update()` method, but it was still looking for a `SelectedCustomerLocation`.  This seems to be an Acumatica-specific issue where they are mutating the type within the cache.

Comment: The error is in code using `PXCache<T>` with those two as generic parameters. I'm not sure what `PXCache<T>` is though.